# Decreasing variable influence over each iteration

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I have a game in which I'm creating bonus items based on a frequency variable.

I would like the generation frequency to become shorter over time. I know how to do that, simply subtract a small number from the frequency every second.

```
Let frequency = 100;

function every1sec {
frequency -= 0.1;
}
```

But as I'm not very mathematically talented, this is the part where I have trouble:

What is a good way to slow down the rate of the frequency becoming shorter over time? So if in the beginning the bonus generation frequency becomes 1 second shorter every minute, how can I make it only become 0.01 seconds shorter after ten minutes have passed. And the part I really have trouble with is this: how can I make the rate of decrease follow a smooth easing curve (instead of a linear decrease).

I don't know the right terminology to search an answer for this. I tried searching for something like "decrease algorithm influence over time" but that didn't get me any useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a simple but rudimentary way you can replace that `0.1` with a variable which  you can also modify with time:

```
let frequency = 100;
let quantity = 0.1;

function every1sec() {
   frequency -= quantity;
   quantity -= 0.01;
}
```

But this will be a little bit junky and should require a lot of tweaking to obtain the desired behaviour.

If you want something smooth you can use JS and mathematical functions which will return points in a curve, like sine and cosine.

```
const MAX_FREQUENCY = 100;
let frequency = MAX_FREQUENCY;
let modifier = 1;

function every1sec() {
   // This way, frequency will be in range [0, MAX_FREQUENCY]
   modifier = Math.min(modifier - 0.1, 0); 
   frequency = MAX_FREQUENCY * Math.sin(modifier);
}
```

Even further, you can customize the whole method:

```js
const STEPS = 30; // Number of times the function needs to be called to reach MIN_FREQUCNY

const MIN_FREQUENCY = 40;
const MAX_FREQUENCY = 100;
const FREQUENCY_RANGE = MAX_FREQUENCY - MIN_FREQUENCY; // 100 - 40 = 60

// ±Math.PI / 2 because Math.sin will be used
const MIN_MODIFIER = -Math.PI / 2;
const MAX_MODIFIER =  Math.PI / 2;
const MODIFIER_RANGE = MAX_MODIFIER - MIN_MODIFIER;
const MODIFIER_STEP = MODIFIER_RANGE / STEPS;


let frequency = MAX_FREQUENCY;
let modifier = MAX_MODIFIER;

// This function can be modified to return different types of curves
// without modifying every1sec function
function curveFunction(modifierValue) {
     // 1 + Math.sin(x) so it will be in range [0, 2] instead of [-1, 1]
     return 1 + Math.sin(modifierValue);
}

function every1sec () {
   modifier = Math.max(modifier - MODIFIER_STEP, MIN_MODIFIER); 
   // FREQUENCY_RANGE * 0.5 because it will be multiplied by a coefficient in range [0, 2]
   frequency = MIN_FREQUENCY + FREQUENCY_RANGE * 0.5 * curveFunction(modifier) ;
}

// The only purpose of this loop is to provide the results of this example
for (let i = 0; i <= STEPS; i++) {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = frequency;
  document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].appendChild(li);
  every1sec();
}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

The last example will modify the frequency starting at a value of 100 and, every second during 30 seconds (steps), updating it to the correspondent value in the range [100, 40] following a sine curve.

Answer (score 1):

To get an exponential decrease, multiply by a fraction.

```js
let frequency = 100;

function every1sec() {
  frequency *= 0.99;
}

let interval = setInterval(function() {
  every1sec();
  console.log(frequency.toFixed(1))
  if (frequency < 50) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 1000);
```